# How can I find out the path to a chrooted environment in which a particular daemon was started?

Tags: linux, process, chroot

I have a setup with several directories where I can chroot and start the same daemon from. I'd like to be able to tell from which of my multiple directories I started the daemon.

I'd like to find it out by using commands only from outside the chrooted environment, and without having to stop the daemon.

Clarification: When I say "the same daemon" what I mean is that the contents of those directories is identical, the only difference is their path in the host environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would accessing `/proc/<pidnumberofyourdaemon>/` help you? There entries such as `cmdline`, `exe` and `fdinfo/*` should give you a hint. Or, just use `lsof` :)

Comment: `/proc/<pid>/cwd` is a symbolic link to the working directory of the process, `/proc/<pid>/cwd` is a symbolic link to the corresponding binary, both from the host environment's perspective. Also, `lsof +p <pid>` shows this path.